# Not to allow incomplete html opening and closing tags in textarea of asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, tags

I have textarea in asp.net page in that i don't want to allow any html tags or any incomplete html tags. I have already done validation for complete html tags but if i put like , or   then all other controls gets bold on next page where we show the all filled information before saving page. Please reply to me ASAP.

Thanks

Comment: Please give some example, for which code is not working.

Comment: I have given example but it's not getting displayed when i save my question. If i have written in text area like <b xuzadsa or sdasdsad /b> then it should prompt the user that doesn't allow html tags.